# Find implementation of specific class in source code

Tags: source-code

I am trying to find the following classes in the source code:

- `SCREEN_OT_screenshot`
- `EXPORT_MESH_OT_stl`

However, I have no idea where to find them and it would be painful to search in every .py of Blender. Is there a way to find a class (especially those two listed above) from console or from the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends whether the operator is from an add-on or implemented in Blender itself. The former will be from a Python script, while the latter is implemented in C or C++ and is accessible through the Python API.

For operators from Python add-ons it's necessary to know the command for the operator, therefore enable the *Developer Extras* in *Edit > Preferences > Interface > Display*. Once enabled, you can right click on buttons and choose *Copy Python Command* from the context menu.

[image: Developer Extras]

[image: Copy Python Command]

When the command is known, the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module can be used to find the source file and the source code. Replace `bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl` with the operator you would like to inspect.

```
import bpy
import inspect


cls = getattr(bpy.types, bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl.idname())
print(inspect.getfile(cls))
print(inspect.getsource(cls))
```

Alternatively, if the class name is already known, it can be used directly.

```
import bpy
import inspect


cls = getattr(bpy.types, 'EXPORT_MESH_OT_stl')
print(inspect.getfile(cls))
print(inspect.getsource(cls))
```

---

The source code of operators, that are implemented in C or C++, can be found by opening an IDE (e.g. Visual Studio Code) or advanced text editor of your choice (e.g. Notepad++) and searching the cloned repository of Blender for the definition of the class name. This approach works for any programming language, including Python scripts.

Alternatively you can use the:

- Diffusion for [Blender](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/repository/master/) or [Blender Add-ons](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/) and search the class name through the *Pattern Search*
- [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/blender/blender) and search the repository using `repo:blender/blender` followed by the class name.

---

The `SCREEN_OT_screenshot` class can be found in  [`/source/blender/editors/screen/screendump.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/screen/screendump.c). The `EXPORT_MESH_OT_stl` class, which is actually named `ExportSTL`, can be found in [`/release/scripts/addons/io_mesh_stl/__init__.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_mesh_stl/__init__.py).

Comment: @UneconscienceUneSource If you want access to the class you need the `idname()`, hence the correct function call would be `cls = getattr(bpy.types, bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide.idname())`. However, this also won't work as the operator is not implemented in Python. You will get an error that looks like `AttributeError: 'RNA_Types' object has no attribute 'MESH_OT_subdivide'` which means you will have to look at Blender's source code.