# How to re-register a built-in operator?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, operator

An existing operator can be overridden by assigning `bl_idname` of an existing operator to a new one. This can be used to extend and even limit the functionality of original operators.

As an example, the [following operator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/184214/31447) is using the `bl_idname` of the original save operator (`wm.save_mainfile`), allowing the `self.filepath` to be manipulated before saving:

```
import bpy

from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import StringProperty
from bpy.types import Operator

class ExportSomeData(Operator, ExportHelper):
    """This appears in the tooltip of the operator and in the generated docs"""
    bl_idname = "wm.save_mainfile"  # 
    bl_label = "Save..."

    # ExportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".blend"

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default="*.blend",
        options={'HIDDEN'},
        maxlen=255, 
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        print(f"Call save as, rejig {self.filepath}")
        #bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=self.filepath)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExportSomeData)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExportSomeData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

However, when converting this into an add-on we would have to re-register the old operator to get the original operator functionality back in order to prevent the user having to *restart blender* <del>or *reload all the scripts*</del> each time.

**Q:** What's a reliable way of re-registering the old operator when the add-on gets disabled?

Comment: AFAICT Reload scripts doesn't revive it either.

Comment: Hi. Seeing as overriding an operator isn't common, I think it would be good to give some context in the question (aside from the code) as to what is meant by 'overriding' in this case. (Also, might be good to quote anything relevant from that other question, just in case it disappears at some point.)

Comment: @brockmann This question sounds like an antipattern.

Comment: How about just adding the operator as a separate one, but instead changing the keyboards shortcuts and menu items to your addon. Them you can restore.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Did not say anything like that"? I'm not saying anything is wrong with the question at all. But you linked to another question, so I'm saying to include any information that is relevant in the question body itself and to give context to what 'override' means here.

Comment: I hadn't heard of 'overriding an operator' in this context before so I've made a few edits to clarify what it means and what that code does. Feel free to rollback if you disagree with them. Cheers.

Comment: As [mentioned](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164370/save-blender-files-with-lowercase/184214#comment308439_184214)  if the [operator has a python class](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168088/find-implementation-of-specific-class-in-source-code) then it is easy to import and reregister.  IMO  The implied question here is how to reregister a builtin operator.. or even for that matter can they be. @Leander re shortcuts and menus... how to replace the Save menu item  becomes an issue.  Overriding is a "one fell swoop" approach

Comment: Many thanks @RayMairlot. Only minor corrections (technical details)...