# Where can I find the source code of save_mainfile in the python API?

Tags: python

I'm looking for the source code of the operator `bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile`.

I searched on their github repo, but I couldn't find the class linked to this operator.
As I want to rewrite this operator, I would like to see how it is implemented to adapt it.

Comment: the source code is written in C++, it's in [/source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_files.cc](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_files.cc) but you can overwrite the Python operator or use an app handler as shown here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/164370/107598

Comment: @Blunder that appears to be a full correct answer. Please post it as such.

Comment: @Blunder I followed every links starting from your link to the app handler. I tried what I found here: [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168107/181412), but it didn't work. However, the code identified that `save_mainfile` is a function in which I can get idname through python code. So, even if it calls a C++ function, it should be written somewhere in python code isn't it?

Comment: I'm not a Python expert but yes, on the Python side, you have a wrapper operator and the operation itself is a C++ function (wm_files.cc:3538). If you enter `type(bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile)` in the Python console it will tell you that it's a `<class 'bpy.ops._BPyOpsSubModOp'>`, a wrapper defined in [blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:22](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py). So, `save_mainfile()` is the constructor? and `save_mainfile.id_name()` is one of its methods that gives you the C++ id='WM_OT_save_mainfile'. There is also a py id='wm.save_mainfile'.

Comment: in ops.py:107 you can see that the operator is called by its py id `ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), ...`. This _op_call seems to do the magic and calls the C++ code. It's imported from _bpy. I have no idea where this _bpy module comes from. But you can call the operator when you do a `from _bpy import ops as ops_module` and then `ops_module.call('wm.save_mainfile', { 'filepath': 'c:/tmp/test.blend'})` for example. Related question: [How to call original operator from operator's override?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/52974/107598)

Comment: @Blunder, thank you for your answer, with further research it seems that `_bpy` is a C module, that why we cannot find it. If you post it as an offical answer, I will accept it, unless I might post answer to my own question.